# fork-join algorithms with ompss

Tags: parallel-processing, task, openmp, dataflow

openMP/ompSs allows to define tasks with specific inputs and outputs so that dependencies among different tasks can be defined.

Most of the examples however feature different functions as tasks connected to each other via dependencies. What about a standard parallel for-based program? Is it possible to define dependencies i.e. among iterations of consecutive 'parallel for' regions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need functions to define dependencies.

Let's take for example a non-commutative operation such as concatenation, here the `inout` dependency will make sure the tasks are always executed in order.

```
char buf_n[11] = {0}, buf_l[11] = {0}, buf_u[11] = {0};
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp single
    {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {

#pragma omp task depend(inout:buf_n) firstprivate(i)
            {
                char add[] = {'0' + i};
                strncat(buf_n, add, 1);
            }

#pragma omp task depend(inout:buf_l) firstprivate(i)
            {
                char add[] = {'a' + i};
                strncat(buf_l, add, 1);
            }

#pragma omp task depend(inout:buf_u) firstprivate(i)
            {
                char add[] = {'A' + i};
                strncat(buf_u, add, 1);
            }

        }

#pragma omp task depend(in:buf_n)
        {
            printf("buf (numbers) is %s\n", buf_n);
        }
#pragma omp task depend(in:buf_l)
        {
            printf("buf (lowercase) is %s\n", buf_l);
        }
#pragma omp task depend(in:buf_u)
        {
            printf("buf (uppercase) is %s\n", buf_u);
        }
    }
}
```

This will always return something like:

```
buf (lowercase) is abcdefghij
buf (uppercase) is ABCDEFGHIJ
buf (numbers) is 0123456789
```

The order of the lines may change, however the concatenations always happen in order (i.e. the letters and numbers are always in the right order).